# How to combine several records in a single letter using Word mail merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a long Excel list with data in the following format:

```
A, B, C
--------
x, y, z1  
x, y, z2  
x, y, z3
```

I want to create a *mail merge* in Word 11 for Mac in the following style for each `x`, `y` , which is a user and `z(n)` is his content:

User: `x`, `y`

Content: `z1`, `z2`, `z3`, ... `z(n)`

How to do that?

Comment: depends on excel version. but you should find out how to create a pivot table in your execel version and then copy that pivot table to word

Comment: `Excel 2007` it is.

Comment: I am quite sure, you can't solve it using Pivot Table, as I have no data that needs sums or other operations.

Comment: I found a solution, yet it seems to work on Windows only. http://cornell.veplan.net/article.aspx?a=3815

Comment: Hello mmb, if it works for you, you can post it as an answer and accept the answer

Comment: Nay, it does not. It works for Windows, but I can't confirm for the solution for OsX (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are detailed answers for this problem, which is called **mail merge using catalog**, most are way too complicated to understand the basic concept.

The answer for this MWE on Word Mac 2011 however would be:

1. Open Tools > Mail Merge Manager
2. Create New > Catalog
3. From 2. Select Recipients List choose your source (XLS, Database...)
4. From 5. click {a} to get source view
5. Enter the following code manually

   ```
   { IF { MERGESEQ } = 1 "{ MERGEFIELD A }" ""}
   { SET A1 { MERGEFIELD }}
   { IF { A1 } <> { A2 } "{ MERGEFIELD B }" "{ MERGEFIELD B}" { SET A2 { MERGEFIELD A }}
   ```
6. From 6. click "Merge to New Document"
7. Done!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is called **catalog** or **sort by category** (the name for the function seems to differ between versions and platforms).

Or in the words of the below quoted solution:

> Sometimes, we want to combine several records in a single letter using
>   Word mail merge.

What it does is to include logic to mail merge, i.e. `if...then...else` for finding out whether certain fields repeat.

There is also a more detailed documentation on Microsoft's support page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294686/en-us

However, it seems, that it only works on Windows machines.